# Mozilla Firefox says Referenceerror event is not defined, no solution has worked

Tags: html, javascript

I have been having troubles with my code. I have searched and found several solutions, but none of them did the trick. The problem is that mozilla firefox gives me an error: event is nod defined. Other browsers work fine. My HTML code to call the function:

```
var demoMap = '<table class="popup" onclick="closePopup(this)"><tr><td>';
```

And javascript

```
function closePopup(e) {

   if ( $(event.target).closest("#map").get(0) == null ) {    
        $(e).fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(e).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited to Stack Overflow. However please bear in mind that you'll probably get downvoted there if you do not show *what* solutions you have attempted.

Answer (score 2):

`event` is not defined. You should change `$(event.target)` to `$(e.target)`.

More - you shouldn't use inline JavaScript in your code.
My solution is to rewrite your code to look like:

```
var demoMap = '<table class="popup"><tr><td>; // Why HTML string in JS?
```

And rest of JS:

```
$('table.popup').on('click', closePopup);
function closePopup(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.closest("#map").get(0) == null ) {    
        $this.fadeOut(500, function () {
            $this.remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: event is defined on some implementation of javascript when a listener is fired

Comment: You shouldn't rely on nonstandard features in production code anyway.